# How can I remove image from feed?

Tags: rss

My feed uses the excerpt, and I want to remove a line of code containing an image.

Example format is...

```
<img class="pagehead" src="/graphics/magazine/307/1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE...

Answering my own question, I'll add this in the hope it'll be useful to someone...

Whilst waiting for answers, I found a solution which seems to work fine.

```
function remove_images( $the_excerpt_rss ) {
$postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $the_excerpt_rss);
return $postOutput;}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'remove_images', 100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize your feed like any other template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds) and use [the_excerpt_rss](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt_rss) function:

```
<?php the_excerpt_rss( $cut, $encode_html ); ?>
```

Or maybe use PHP [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php) function :

```
// Autorise <p> et <a>
echo strip_tags( $text, '<p><a>' );
```

Comment: Thanks. And that'll remove the whole line - everything between the html brackets?

Comment: Strip_tags function will remove html & php tags in string, not the texts in it.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get the-excerpt-rss to accept parameters, so strip_tags looks to be a better option - thanks for the useful link, it'll be helpful.