# remove enclosure url from feed

Tags: images, feed, feedburner

I searched the whole internet, including this website, but there is no written way on how to remove the enclosure url from the WordPress feed. 
 I want to remove it because FeedBurner is adding the image url directly in the email that it is sending to subscribers.
 The reason doesn't really matter I guess, so simply how to remove enclosure url from the feed?

```
<enclosure url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/whatever-image.jpg" length="5873907" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

the feed also has this line, which I also want to remove:

```
<media:content url="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/whatever-image.jpg" width="7360" height="4912" medium="image" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

any idea on how to do this? everything I tried until now failed, including some answers on this [website](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238383/how-can-i-remove-image-from-feed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look if your posts have any assigned `enclosure` meta keys, that could trigger the `rss_enclosure()` core function to print the `<enclosure>` tag. Otherwise you can try this demo plugin:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Remove RSS Enclosure **/

add_filter( 'rss_enclosure', '__return_empty_string' );
```

It looks like you've a plugin that's adding the `<media:content>` tag, e.g. via the `rss2_item` hook. So check your plugins. Otherwise you can try this demo plugin to remove all extra rss2 items:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Remove All Extra rss2 Items **/

add_action( 'rss2_head', function()
{
    remove_all_actions( 'rss2_item' );
} );
```

We can do similar for *atom*- and *rss* feeds.

Remember to request the feed with an *url cache buster* when debugging.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. @whitelord